# Round/Limit ms-duration (DateTime::diff) to one digit

Tags: php

I have a `Start-DateTime` and an `End-DateTime` -object, both containing milliseconds.
I want to calculate the duration (`->diff`) between those.

The code looks like this:

```
$StartDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat( "Y-m-d H:i:s.v", "2021-02-07 09:08:46.000" );
$EndDateTime   = DateTime::createFromFormat( "Y-m-d H:i:s.v", "2021-02-07 09:09:10.200" );
$Interval = $StartDateTime->diff( $EndDateTime );

echo $Interval->format( "%H:%I:%S.%F" );
```

The result is `00:00:24.200000`.

This is quite OK, but I only want **one** decimal digit (milliseconds) like `00:00:24.2`.
Ideally the result/one digit gets rounded, but only if it is easy doable. (one-liner?)

Is there an easy solution?

Thank you

Comment: Just use `substr()` to remove the last five characters. Pretty basic stuff.

Comment: First I did use "%f" as format-parameter and not "%F", which had a variable length. Well yes, as it is constantly 6 digits now I really could use `substr`. Rounding would be much more difficult I guess?

Comment: Since it's not actually a number rounding won't work unless you want to `explode()` the string, `round()` the value, and and the concatenate it back together again. But not exactly a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

The result of DateTime::diff is a DateInterval. DateInterval::createFromDateString can be used to create an interval with milliseconds and microseconds.

```
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('23 Seconds 345 Milliseconds 67 Microseconds');
echo $interval->format("%H:%I:%S.%F");
//00:00:23.345067
```

The output with %F and DateInterval::format always has 6 digits. To round the microseconds, we can change the property f. We can use round() because the property f is of type float.

```
$interval->f = round($interval->f, 1);
echo $interval->format("%H:%I:%S.%F");
//00:00:23.300000
```

The result is rounded to one place, but the output is still made with 6 digits.
We can now remove the last 5 digits with substr().

```
echo substr($interval->format("%H:%I:%S.%F"),0,-5);
//00:00:23.3
```

If you only want the output with one decimal place and rounding, you can do that:

```
echo $interval->format("%H:%I:%S").ltrim(sprintf('%0.1f',$interval->f),'0');
//00:00:23.3
```